# Separate number with commas on a string in IOS UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, formatting

I'm binding json datas. Json send me km (kilometer) format float . like ; km=850.564636

I want put in cell this km data. like 850.56

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"KmCellTableViewCell";

KmCellTableViewCell *cell = (KmCellTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSString *system = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];

    if ([system isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"]) {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KmCellTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }else
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KmCellTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
}

Vehicle *GetVehicle = (Vehicle *)[ResultVehicles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.txtPlate.text = [GetVehicle Plate];
cell.txtKm.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ km",[GetVehicle km]]; return cell; }
```

i formatted another class. but not in cell.i have to formatted in cell.  like this in -(void)FirstBinding{} method

```
Vehicle *GetVehicle = (Vehicle *)[ResultVehicles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.txtPlate.text = [GetVehicle Plate];

cell.txtKm.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ km",[GetVehicle km]];    return cell;}double km = [[vehiclesList objectForKey:@"total_km"] doubleValue];
        NSNumberFormatter* nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        nf.positiveFormat = @"#,##0.00";
        NSString* s = [nf stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: km]];
        txtKilometer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",s];
```

Comment: you are saying the json looks like this {"km":872.54}, right?

Comment: I think it can easily be done using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",km];`

Comment: no.  {"km":872.548564564546} . my code is working but in cell view like this. i want see 872.55 . so nf.positiveFormat = @"#,##0.00";

Comment: @iphonic my friend. km is item in GetVehicle . i trying your say. and doesnt change

Comment: @ulaslaslas you have to cast your `km` string to a float: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",[km floatValue]];`, you don't need a `NSNumberFormatter` for this.